# Cat the contents of a file directly into the clipboard in cygwin terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, cygwin, cat

I want to *cat* the contents of a text file directly into the clipboard rather than display the contents on the screen in a bash terminal in Cygwin.

i.e.,

```
cat textfile.txt > /dev/clip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way to do this is to call the Windows clip program directly:

i.e.,

```
clip < textfile.txt
```

Now the text from the file will be available to paste using the mouse right click or ctrl+v.

Answer (score 0):

putclip and getclip

```
<command> | putclip
```

or

```
putclip < <filename>
```

similar with getclip
They are in the `cygutils-extra` package

```
$ cygcheck -p bin/putclip
Found 6 matches for bin/putclip
...
cygutils-extra-1.4.15-2 - cygutils-extra: A collection of simple utilities (other tools
) (installed binaries and support files)
cygutils-extra-1.4.16-1 - cygutils-extra: A collection of simple utilities (other tools
)
cygutils-extra-1.4.16-2 - cygutils-extra: A collection of simple utilities (other tools
)
```

Comment: added where to find them